# No error but no output when plotting map with folium and choropleth in Python

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, choropleth, folium

I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/docs-v0.5.0/quickstart.html#Choropleth-maps). Goal is to produce a map that shades each zip code according to a value tied to said zip code.

I couldn't produce an output even tho there're no errors using jupyter notebook. my code is below.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.cm
    import folium
    import os
    import json
    data=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/cuezy/Desktop/ML/Python/import data/zipcodetest.csv')
    #initialize: load data
    zip_geo=os.path.join('C:/Users/cuezy/Desktop/ML/Python/import data/zip', 'zips_us.json')
    zip_rsrp=os.path.join('C:/Users/cuezy/Desktop/ML/Python/import data', 'zipcodetest.csv')
    zip_data = pd.read_csv(zip_rsrp)

m = folium.Map(location=[40.006, -75.285], zoom_start=13)

m.choropleth(
    geo_data=zip_geo,
    name='choropleth',
    data=zip_data,
    columns=['Zip', 'RSRP'],
    key_on='feature.id',
    fill_color='BuGn',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='RSRP'
)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

The csv file I made up has 2 columns, headers are Zip and RSRP (2 digit integer), and 5 rows of numbers. The Json file is just a zip code json file downloaded from US census website.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a cell on your tutorial and last istruction is `data=...` you wont’t to see any output in [Jupyter notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/4.0.x/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Index.ipynb).
If you end your cell with `m`, like tutorial, you will see a map.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, actually my code did end with 'm', I just pasted it wrong in the question.

Comment: Just voted. my problem actually still isn't solved; with the code above I'm still not getting an out put and no error neither..